# What is workflow in CRM2011 For sending mails after getting Approved?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I create one campaign with the "**Sending for approval**" status. Then i moved to approved authority persons through the assign records via workflow. He open that Campaign and **approved** that particular record's status. My question is how to get that **approved** status in my workflow using CRM2011 or how to check that campaign is approved/otherStatus via my workflow? What is the workflow for getting that response?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand well your question. You want launch a workflow when the status changed for approved. So you can launch your workflow when the "Record status change", after that you can check if the status is "Approved". Check this [example](http://dynamic-crm.com/crm-dynamics-workflow/).

Comment: I create one campaign with "Sending for approval" Status. Then i assigned the approval persons for getting "Approved". How to getting that response of the campaign is approved or not?

Comment: Hi @V.V you have to add a new workflow when a CampaignResponse is created and you have a field ParentCampaign that identifies the origin campaign. You can't have a continuous workflow that cares with the distribute campaigns to approve a wait for an approve or reject